# File sharing discovery in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos-carbon, afp

I'm trying to programmatically discover and then mount network volumes shared using OS X's file sharing from a Cocoa app. I'm using NSNetServiceBrowser to discover which servers are advertising file sharing - easy enough.

My question is about the next step - how do you discover what shares are available for a given machine? ie. given that AFP URLs look something like this:

```
afp://SomeMac._afpovertcp._tcp.local/SomeVolume
afp://SomeMac._afpovertcp._tcp.local/OtherVolume
```

how do I discover the share names that make up that last url component? Surely I don't have to make low-level AFP calls for this!

Answer (score 2):

If by "low-level AFP calls" you mean `FPGetSrvrParms()`, then almost certainly that's exactly what you would need to do. Bonjour (`NSNetServiceBrowser`) is intended to *discover* services, not perform service-specific communications. AFP is the service. Each volume is not its own service any more than you would expect to access individual HTTP URLs through `NSNetServiceBrowser`.

I don't believe there's a Cocoa interface to AFP. Bill Monk wrote up some [simple code for mounting](http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg04824.html) that you might find useful.

Comment: Yes I was hoping not to have to open a TCP socket and speak AFP over it in order to discover the share names before the mounting stage. Looks like I might have to though.